# How to call here place api to get accurate nearby place name

Tags: here-api

one of my client they using here map and api, for the bellow lat lon they get this

```
23.759769,90.411991
South 75m,Ideal Trade Centre,Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh
```

but when i am using

```
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=23.7598%2C90.412&show_content=&Geolocation=geo%3A23.7598%2C90.412&X-Mobility-Mode=drive&Accept-Language=en-GB&app_id=5B88sPuZ1iyF3RjMLnqK&app_code=jcz5u1RQZ4HiY7FJLD0bvA
```

this give me

```
{ Siddik School } 21
{ Mamataz Bakery } 39
{ Ahad Bakery House } 45
```

etc

I need a help to understand how they getting bellow result from **here API** for that lat/lon

75m,Ideal Trade Centre,Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh

if some one can hellp me to understand what i am missing i would be really greatfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your client is using the [Reverse Geocode API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/what-is.html), while you're trying to look for places at that same location, using the Places API. Note that the Reverse Geocode has more *modes* available than  *retrieveAddresses*.

However, there are several ways your client could get to such result. For example, `/discover/around` filtered on *business-services* category returns Ideal Trade Centre among other places: [example](https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=23.7598%2C90.412&cat=business-services&size=5&Accept-Language=en-GB&app_id=appId&app_code=appCode)

Your best bet is to ask your client how exactly they are using the API.

Comment: I already looked at Reverse Geocode, it only gives this
Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh
it does not give areas there like
Ideal Trade Centre,Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh
may be i am missing some thing, please let me know what i am missing

Comment: @Micahel P.Bazos, Thanks for the hits, the problem is, the client is not going to tell me how they doing, all i know they usig here api, but i think i am close, tell me one thing, is there any way to provide direction (south,north,east , west) and check which place is close by ?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport , Exactly thats my question, why they not using first 2 , why 3rd one,  the client is in China, I asked them, they did not mention anything, same question, can we pass direction i.e from south whicih places is close by ? some thing like this ? because the out put i see is like this
``` South 75m,Ideal Trade Centre,Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh```, so woundering if we can pass direction to get location